Vue3 DOM ref onMounted addEventListener
I have this component in vue3:
<template>
    <div class="list-cell">
        <div
            v-for="(value, index) in lines"
            ref="items"
            :key="index"
            class="list-cell--item"
        >
            {{ value }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Ref, ref, onMounted, onUnmounted, PropType } from 'vue';

const items: Ref<HTMLElement[]> = ref([]);

defineProps({
    lines: { type: Array as PropType<string[]>, default: () => [] },
});

const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    console.log(1);
};
const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    console.log(2);
};

onMounted(() => {
    items.value.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('mouseenter', handleMouseEnter);
        item.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
    });
});
onUnmounted(() => {
    items.value.forEach((item) => {
        item.removeEventListener('mouseenter', handleMouseEnter);
        item.removeEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
    });
});
</script>

this component is a simplified version of a cell in a table with multiple rows and paging.
It doesn't always log 1 or 2 for all the cells
but if I add timeout to the event listener it always logs 1 or 2 correctly:
setTimeout(() => {
    items.value.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('mouseenter', handleMouseEnter);
        item.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
    });
}, 5000);

anyone have an idea why?
this is the table that uses the cell:
<Table>
    <TableHeader
        slot="table-header"
        :columns="tableColumns"
    />
    <TableBody
        slot="table-body"
    >
        <TableRow
            v-for="(entity, index1) in dataSource"
            :key="currentItemOffset + index1"
            :row="entity"
            rowid="index1"
        >
            <TableCell
                v-for="(item, index2) in entity"
                :key="currentItemOffset + index2"
            >
                <ComponentWithIssue
                    :lines="item"
                ></ComponentWithIssue>
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    </TableBody>
</Table>


Why don't you Vue's baked-in @mouseover event listener on each item? Also, give a try to nextTick, a cleaner approach to avoid using a fix like a timeout.

@mouseleave/@mouseenter did work - thanks!
but do u have an idea why the way I tried didn't work?
and tried nextTick, it didn't work.

You cannot bind events to your app while the DOM is still being built, components' lifecycles are in progress, and maybe other thread-blocking NPM packages etc. nextTick is supposed to wait until your DOM is done with all of this (this includes potential child components afaik too). You should be able to run it after the onMounted event. But anyway, if you plan on using querySelector, it's not the best way to go: rather stick with using Vue's state management so that way you don't have a difference in terms of managing your UI and keeping everything under Vue's reactivity.

OP solved his issue by using the following events:

@mouseleave
@mouseenter


nextTick could also be used but it's more of a hack than the better and more common way of doing things. Should be used occasionally with some 3rd party packages needing extra time to initialize. Still, it is better than using setTimeout from a user's UX perspective.
